# Define a variable based on variables from different data frames in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to define a variable in df1 based on variable in df1 `df1$person_id` and a variable in df2 `df2$gender`. The structure is the following

*I have updated the structure of the data because the previous one was wrong.*

```
df1 <- structure(list(person_id = c("15813, 15837, 18118, 16672", "8818, 8132, 18045, 18051, 15916, 10204, 18042, 12455, 18218, 18046, 18050, 18165, 18043, 18052, 18048", "8818, 8132, 18051, 18045, 18042, 10204, 12455, 15916, 18218, 18046, 18050, 18165, 18043, 18052, 18048"), gender = c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 12:14, class = "data.frame")
df2 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(278L, 363L, 156L), .Label = c("10096", "10204", "11094", "11096", "11097", "11098", "11102", "11106", "11109", "11116", "11118", "11121"), class = "factor"), gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output is two columns - `df1$person_id` and `df1$gender`. `df1$gender` may have three options: either all male, or all female, or both.
Please, could you help me?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not merging. `authors$ids` has from one to several people, who may be of different genders.

Comment: The desired output is two columns - `authors$ids` and `authors$genders` . `authors$genders`  may have three options: either all male, or all female, or both.

Comment: Yes you're right. Not the first time I read a question too fast when I think it's about joining (and there are so many of those...) - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
# Note the stringsAsFactors=T
authors <- data.frame(ids = c("2, 1", "3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8", "6", "1, 4, 7, 8"), genders = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gender <- structure(list(id = 1:8, gender = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)),row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Let's normalise your groups
groups <- 
  authors %>%
  # create ID for the group of author
  mutate(group_id = 1:n()) %>% 
  # split authors
  mutate(author_id = strsplit(ids, split = ", ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(author_id) %>%
  # cast to integer for compatibility with the other table
  mutate(author_id = as.integer(author_id)) %>% 
  select(group_id, author_id)

# This is the normalized version of your group / author relationship
groups
#> # A tibble: 13 x 2
#>    group_id author_id
#>       <int>     <int>
#>  1        1         2
#>  2        1         1
#>  3        2         3
#>  4        2         4
#>  5        2         5
#>  6        2         6
#>  7        2         7
#>  8        2         8
#>  9        3         6
#> 10        4         1
#> 11        4         4
#> 12        4         7
#> 13        4         8

# Technically this is the "author" table since it contains author details
# I'll rename it for clarity
authors <- gender


group_gender <- 
  groups %>%
  left_join(authors, by = c("author_id" = "id")) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarise(gender = case_when(
    all(gender == 1) ~ "Male",
    all(gender == 2) ~ "Female",
    TRUE ~ "Both"
  ))

# I took the liberty to create a single column with the gender. 
# It makes it easier to compute gender stats.
group_gender
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   group_id gender
#>      <int> <chr> 
#> 1        1 Male  
#> 2        2 Both  
#> 3        3 Male  
#> 4        4 Both
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: after many tries, your solution worked out with my real data! thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might do this using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. No need for loops.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

authors %>% 
  mutate(record=row_number(), genders=NULL, id=ids) %>% 
  separate_rows(id, convert=TRUE) %>% 
  left_join(gender) %>% 
  group_by(record, ids) %>% 
  summarize(genders=paste(gender, collapse=", "),
            all_male=all(gender==1),
            all_female=all(gender==2),
            both=any(gender==1) & any(gender==2),
            class=case_when(all(gender==1)~"Male",
                            all(gender==2)~"Female",
                            TRUE~"Both"))
```

Basically we first expand the comma separated values into separate rows. That allows us to easily join the data to the gender info, then we summarize to check the distribution of genders among the authors.

This gives

```
  record ids              genders          all_male all_female both  class
   <int> <fct>            <chr>            <lgl>    <lgl>      <lgl> <chr>
1      1 2, 1             1, 1             TRUE     FALSE      FALSE Male 
2      2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 FALSE    FALSE      TRUE  Both 
3      3 6                1                TRUE     FALSE      FALSE Male 
4      4 1, 4, 7, 8       1, 1, 2, 1       FALSE    FALSE      TRUE  Both
```

Comment: Wow, the `separate_rows` function makes it trivial! +1

Comment: when I do it in the faux data, it works. but when i reapply it to my real data it gives me  _Error: Can't join on 'id' x 'id' because of incompatible types (character / integer)_

Comment: @MrFlick do you know how to figure out that issue?

Comment: It’s hard to say what’s going on if your data doesn’t match the reproducible example. Are your ids meant to be character values or numeric values? How are they coded in both tables?

Comment: I have updated the reproducible example. Could you, please, check one more time?

Comment: The data you posted now has changed column names and is not valid R code (there is a malformed factor there). Maybe just try with `separate_rows(id, convert=FALSE)`. Looks like your IDs probably aren't actually numbers but rather factors.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
idx <- strsplit(as.character(authors$ids), split = ', ')

transform(
  authors,
  genders = ifelse(
    sapply(idx, function(x) all(c(1, 2) %in% gender$gender[match(x, gender$id)])),
    'Both',
    ifelse(
      sapply(idx, function(x) any(1 == gender$gender[match(x, gender$id)]) & !any(2 == gender$gender[match(x, gender$id)])),
      'Male',
      'Female')
  )
)
```

Output:

```
               ids genders
1             2, 1    Male
2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8    Both
3                6    Male
4       1, 4, 7, 8    Both
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `genderize` function based on `table`. And apply it on a `strsplit`. I've changed `author` data so that one row has both male.

```
genderize <- function(id) {
  r <- table(gender[as.double(id), "gender"])
  if (length(r) == 2) r <- 3
  else r <- as.double(names(r))
  factor(r, levels=1:3, labels=c("female", "male", "both"))
}

authors$genders <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(authors$ids), ", "), genderize)
               ids genders
1             3, 7    male
2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8    both
3                6  female
4       1, 4, 7, 8    both
```

---

*Data*

```
authors <- structure(list(ids = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("1, 4, 7, 8", 
"3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8", "3, 7", "6"), class = "factor"), genders = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

gender <- structure(list(id = 1:8, gender = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this solution gives me `integer(0)` or `1` in `authors$gender`, when I apply the code on my real data

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha Oh, I was assuming that the structure of your sample data resembles that of your real data. Could you fix that?

Comment: I just don't not how... I can say that `authors$ids` is `character`, `gender$gender` is `integer`, and `gender$id` is `factor`. Maybe I should convert them before running your code? But when I convert `authors$ids` from character to any other class, it coerces into NAs

Comment: I tried conversion according to your suggestions, but it works fine for me (my data is same as your sample data, I just changed `2, 1` to `3, 7` in first row.). Perhaps you can provide an excerpt of your real data using `dput(realData[1:3, c("ids", "genders")])`?

Comment: `df1 <- structure(list(person_id = c("15813, 15837, 18118, 16672", "8818, 8132, 18045, 18051, 15916, 10204, 18042, 12455, 18218, 18046, 18050, 18165, 18043, 18052, 18048", "8818, 8132, 18051, 18045, 18042, 10204, 12455, 15916, 18218, 18046, 18050, 18165, 18043, 18052, 18048"), gender = c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 12:14, class = "data.frame")` and

Comment: `df2 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(278L, 363L, 156L), .Label = c("10096",                                                            "10204", "11094", "11096", "11097", "11098", "11102", "11106",                                                              "11109", "11116", "11118", "11121"), class = "factor"), gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I have deleted from the second data frame a bunch of numbers in this brackets to fit the output I received `.Label = c("10096", "10204" DELETED FROM HERE)`

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha That did not work. probably better using the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60567992/edit) button below your question.